# How to show current months projects in list, where current month date is between A and B on new year roll over

Tags: mysql, sql

Last year I set up a project management system, but now as we're on a new year I've been bit in my ass by some newbie coding (of me) :)

So now I really need your help to understand how to fix this in a good way once and for all.

## The error:

The major problem right now is in the year roll over, right now my SQL query dosn't understand that the month of the new year (1) is larger than the current years (12) which then dosn't show the right projects in the list.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

## This is my current SQL Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) between MONTH(project_start) and MONTH(project_delivery)
AND YEAR(CURDATE()) between YEAR(project_start) and YEAR(project_delivery)
order by project_id
```

## This is the raw structure of the table projects:

```
Project_id projet_start projet_delivery
1          2018-12-20   2018-12-22
2          2018-12-25   2018-12-29
3          2018-12-28   2018-12-28
4          2018-12-30   2019-01-22
```

Comment: Include both year and month? compare it in YYYYMM format, so that the later month is always larger in all cases. For example, 201901 > 201812

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your comment, I understand, but how can I then achieve a list of projects that are only in the current month?

Comment: Convert every date to that format as well, then compare to check if it matches. For example, 2018-12-20 and 2018-12-25 will be converted into 201812, but 2019-01-22 will be converted into 201901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BETWEEN works for actual dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE CURDATE() between project_start and project_delivery
order by project_id
```

If you wanted everything from the month (month granularity) rather than day granularity:

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE CURDATE() between DATE_SUB(project_start, INTERVAL DAY(project_start)-1 DAY) and 
  DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(project_delivery, INTERVAL DAY(project_delivery) DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
order by project_id
```

So if a project started on Dec 5th and finished on Jan 19th, this would give everything between Dec 1st and Jan 31st. Do bear in mind though that if any date on Jan 31st also has a time component (i.e. later than midnight), it will mean it's fractionally after this end date and won't show.

Comment if that's the case and you want help solving it (easiest to not use `BETWEEN` because it's always inclusive at each end, use `<` which is exclusive)

Update: Projects that have had some activity this month, i.e a project that:

- started before, ended during
- started before, ended after
- started during, ended during
- started during, ended after

The common thing all these have is that the start date of the project is before the end of this month, and also the end date of the project is after the first of this month

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE 
  --started before the end of this month
  project_start < DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
  --ended after the start of this month
  project_delivery > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) DAY) 

order by project_id
```

Doing a `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) DAY)` is a rather convoluted way of writing "subtract the current day number from the current date" i.e. `2019-01-02 minus 2 -> 2018-12-31`. We look for dates `>` this (so as not to include it)

Similarly, `DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` Takes the current date, subs DAY-1 (so just 1 this time, not 2) off it to reach 1st of this month, then adds a month on to get to first of next month. `2019-01-02 -> 2019-01-01 -> 2019-02-01`. Again `<` it so it's exclusive

There's a bug in going the other way (add a month then sub the day) if you're on eg the 31st of jan and you add a month first - there is no 31st of feb so mysql will cap at 28th of feb, then sub 31 days off it, giving a date that is not the end of jan (i.e. 28th of jan)

Comment: Hi Caius, and thanks for your well described answer. I think that I follow you on each part, however. If I want to only show the projects that are listed in the current month (Jan 1st to Jan 31st), otherwise in the same way as the code above. How could I achieve something like that?

Comment: So essentially you're saying you want to show projects that have had some kind of activity this month? In code terms the logic for this is usually "project starts before the end of this month AND ends after the start of this month"

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for :) 
To show:
 projects that starts before the end of this month AND ends after the start of this month

Comment: Edited post to include another query to fulfil this

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the help! This works just as mentioned above. However, I need something else when I'm testing it out. The start and end date dosn't matter. As long as there is at least one day in the current month. So for example. If the project started in 2018-05-05 and have a delivery in 2019-01-02, it should show in the january summary.

Comment: Caius,
I assume the other way around will work for this?

  curdate() > DATE_SUB(project_start, INTERVAL DAY(project_start) DAY) and 
  curdate() < DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(project_delivery, INTERVAL DAY(project_delivery) - 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

Comment: Yeah, after all that I think I got my project_start and project_delivery the wrong way round! (Fixed)

Answer (score 0):

Just use date comparisons:

```
select p.*
from projects p
where curdate() >= project_start and
      curdate() <= project_delivery;
```

I'm not sure why you would want to break the dates into their time components.  However, that is totally unnecessary to compare them.

If you want to just do the comparison at the month level, then one method is to convert the values to months:

```
select p.*
from projects p
where year(curdate()) * 12 + month(curdate()) >=  year(project_start) * 12 + month(project_start) and
      year(curdate()) * 12 + month(curdate()) <= year(project_delivery) * 12 + month(project_delivery);
```

Alternatively, just move the dates to the beginning of months:

```
select p.*
from projects p
where curdate() >= project_start + interval 1 - day(project_start) day and
      curdate() < ( project_delivery + interval (1 - day(project_delivery) day) + interval 1 month;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Gordon, as I understand this would do for the month/year roll over problem. 

But if I then only want to show the projects that are equal to the current month (which could be any project between date A and B). How could I achieve that?